# Searching C Drive for a file with VBScript

Tags: recursion, vbscript

I am very new to VBScript, and I am trying to write a simple script that will extract a file in a directory to a new directory. So far this is what I have (and it works well):

```
'USER VAR REPRESENTS WINDOWS USERNAME
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
user=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserName%")

'FOLDER TO BE EXTRACTED
ZipFile="C:\Users\"&user&"\Downloads\Test.zip" 

'LOCATION TO EXTRACT FILES
ExtractTo="C:\Users\"&user&"\desktop" 

'EXTRACT ZIP FILE
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).items
objShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)

Set fso = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Now, if possible, if the "Desktop" folder cannot be found, or the "Test.zip" file cannot be found, I would like to search the C Drive for them, and then proceed with extracting, etc. I have seen some examples, but I cannot understand how to replicate them. How can I search the entire C drive and sub folders for these files?

Help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In general a recursive search can be done like this:

```
Function SearchFolder(fldr, name)
  Set SearchFolder = Nothing
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If LCase(f.Name) = LCase(name) Then
      Set SearchFolder = f
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Set result = SearchFolder(sf, name)
    If Not result Is Nothing Then
      Set SearchFolder = result
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = SearchFolder(fso.GetFolder("C:\"), "Test.zip")
```

However, searching a whole drive that way will take quite some time. Also there are several folders that users don't have access to, so you'll have to account for that if you want to implement a search like this.

Comment: Alright, that is true, thanks. Basically, (and this is not included in my code) I would like to find a subfolder of itunes, that will be in different locations on different computers. Any ideas on how I could do this without going through the entire c drive? On my computer, for example, you have to go to music > iTunes > (subfolder). On other computers it might be in documents, or someplace else (and I am not talking about the iTunes folder with the program files, this is a different one)

Comment: You mean the library, I know. The `My Music` user shell folder is the default location for it, which can be read from the registry (`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\My Music`). I don't use iTunes on Windows, so I don't know if you could pick a different location without that value being changed, and where that different location would be stored.